# Subclassed CALayer animation function does not animate

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, cabasicanimation

Currently, I have subclassed CALayer to create a animatable bottom border for my UITextField. However, my `animateColor` function is not working. I've tested to see if the function is being called and it is. However, no animation is taking place. What am I doing wrong?

```
class KTextFieldBottomBorder:CALayer {

override init!() {
    super.init()
    commonInit()
}

override init!(layer: AnyObject!) {
    super.init(layer: layer)
    commonInit()
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

func commonInit() {

    // Appearance

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor

}

// MARK: Animations

func animateColor (endingColor:UIColor, duration:CFTimeInterval) {
    var colorAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "color")
    colorAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
    colorAnimation.toValue = endingColor.CGColor
    colorAnimation.duration = duration
    colorAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    super.addAnimation(colorAnimation, forKey: "color")
    println("X")
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the property that shall be animated by setting the `keyPath`.

```
colorAnimation.keyPath = "backgroundColor"
```

The `key` argument of `addAnimation` is merely used as an identifier for the animation.

Comment: Correct. I've changed it directly at the `colorAnimation` declaration to `var colorAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "backgroundColor")` to reduce verbosity. Thanks.